# angular declaring data;any how to fetch something inside that variable

Tags: angular

i have variable `data: any` and in that variable i stored something like this :

```
 { name:"something",username:"something",number:"4"}
```

I tried this.data.name but shows empty string when i try to console.log

how to take data from it to formgroup in ts and angular 6
this is the code :

```
constructor(route: ActivatedRoute, http: Http, router: Router) {
this.http = http;
this.router = router;
this.route = route;
}
ngOnInit() {

this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
let id = +params['id'];
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
headers.append("token",localStorage.getItem("token"));
this.http.get('http://localhost/it255/getroom.php?id='+id,{headers:headers}).pipe(map(res => res.json()),share()).subscribe(data=>{
this.data = data.data;
console.log(this.data.roomname);
this.populateFormcontrol();
},err => {
this.router.navigate(['./']);
})
});
}
populateFormcontrol(){
    this.changeRoomForm.setValue({roomname:this.data.roomname,beds:this.data.beds, tv:this.data.tv});
}
}
```

Comment: you are accessing the values correctly just make sure you are accessing value after intialization of `data` variable.

Comment: @AnshumanJaiswal and how would you declare for example  some name to formcontrol name

Comment: @ans i think that it is accessed after the initialization

Comment: Please show the code where you access this variable including the surrounding method-bodies.

Comment: @DiabolicWords  I edit my posts with methods

Comment: What's the output of `console.log(data);` if you put it right before `console.log(this.data.roomname);`?

Comment: @DiabolicWords  []length: 0__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: Okay, so you don't get any value by your request. Unfortunately, at this point I can only recommend to use the network view in the developer tools of your browser an check what data you actually receive.

Comment: @DiabolicWords i managed to find and know i receive what i want in console when i put console.log(data.roomname),just still can;t put it inside formcontrolname

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, referring to the [API-docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl), you can only set one value at a time.

Like this:

```
this.changeRoomForm.setValue({roomname: this.data.roomname, {});
this.changeRoomForm.setValue({beds: this.data.beds, {});
this.changeRoomForm.setValue({tv: this.data.tv, {});
```

Please, try it this way.

Comment: and what is this for curly braces after whis data.roomname ? never mind now it gives me an error for beds, and that value from db is number,maybe it is because of that ?

Comment: Considering the API, this pair of curly braces is for options. You can leave it out as default is `{}`anyway. I don't develop angular in on model driven approach, so this something I have no further idea for, sorry.